# Is there any possibility to get $\Gamma \subset \Lambda$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $f,g$ be $n$-degree and $m$-degree polynomials over $\mathbb C$ respectively, with $n>m$.

- Set $\Lambda=\{x \in \mathbb C~:~ f(x)=0 \}$ and $\Gamma=\{x \in \mathbb C~:~ g(x)=0 \}$.
- Assume $h \circ f=g \circ h$, where $h:~\Lambda \to \Gamma$ is a surjection.

> Is there any possibility to get $\Gamma \subset \Lambda$ ?

Let $\gamma \in \Gamma$, we need to show $g(\gamma)=0$.

By the surjective property of $h$ for any $\lambda \in \Lambda$ there is some some $\alpha \in \Gamma$ so that $h(\alpha)=\lambda$ but this does not help me.

Any comments please.

Comment: You mean $h: \Lambda \to \Gamma$ I think. And $h \circ f=g \circ h $ is defined on $\Gamma$ only. Right?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, yes exactly

Comment: can you show us a nontrivial triple $f,g,h$ such that $f,g$ are polynomials , $h$ is surjective and $h \circ f=g \circ h$?

Comment: @miracle173, I have an example and it gave negative answer to my question

Comment: @Mathlearner So please show us your example.

Comment: @miracle173, we have already one in the nice answer below. Should I write my example too ?

Comment: @Mathlearner thx, I think this isn't necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda \in \Lambda$, which means $f(\lambda) = 0$. The equality

$$h \circ f = g \circ h$$ translates into

$$h(0) = h(f(\lambda)) = (h \circ f)(\lambda) = (g \circ h)(\lambda) = g(h(\lambda)) =0$$ as $h(\lambda) \in \Gamma$.
We get that $0$ belongs to $\Lambda$ and $h(0)=0$.

Now clearly, we need not have $\Lambda \subset \Gamma$. And any $f,g$ such that $f(0)=g(0) =0$ where $g$ doesn't divide $f$ will provide a counterexample. Like $f(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)$ and $g(x) = x(x-3)$ with $h(0)=0$ and $h(1)=h(2)=3$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice calculation. Do you have any supporting examples or situations under some conditions ?

Comment: what is $h(x)$ in you counterexample? we you only defined h(0), h(1), h(2)

Comment: @miracle173 In the question, $h$ is only defined on $\Gamma$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thx, I missed this